# Find specific value in between XML element

Tags: xml, find, wildcard, text-editor, zipcode

I'm trying to edit an XML file to remove all +4 in zipcodes. There are 90,000 records to go through.

This is what the field/element looks like:

`<postal-code>08556-0086</postal-code>`

This is what we want it to look like:

`<postal-code>08556</postal-code>`

Can I do a find and replace in a text editor ? 
If yes, how would I search for this in the file?
If no, what is the best way to go about editing the zipcodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In notepad++ you can replace using regular expression: Ctrl+F -> Replace -> Search mode: "Regular expression"

The following strings are working for me:

Find what: `-[0-9]+</postal-code>`

Replace with: `</postal-code>`

Comment: OMG! Thats what I have been trying to accomplish. Thank you!